# Flutter how to turn off device light programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way of turning device light ON/OFF programmatically in Flutter, any plugin or anything else?

Comment: may be you have to try this https://pub.dev/packages/lamp

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Thanks but I am not asking for Torch, I am asking for screen/display light.

Answer (score -1):

You can do with smart switch, which can be made by using Sonoff device [Sonoff](https://www.sonoff.in/). then you need to map mqtt server with RestAPI. then you can control the smart switched remotely.